# Downside to interning strings?

Tags: python

Consider:

```
a = str(123456789)
b = str(123456789)
a is b # False
```

The latter line evaluates as `False` because `a` and `b` are not the same object, even though they could be (because strings are immutable). Hence, if I have a lot of "copies" of the same string alive, I may be using way more memory than I need. This is why `intern` (Py2) and `sys.intern` (Py3) exist!

```
a = intern(str(123456789))
b = intern(str(123456789)) # Call to "intern" technically pointless
a is b # True
```

Is there any downside to using `intern` from a memory perspective? (So beyond the tiny time cost to call a function.) I understand from the docs (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) that a string only stays in the intern table for as long as I keep a reference to it alive, so in the case of only having one copy of the string, that should use the same amount of memory as just assigning to the string directly, and if I have multiple copies, then obviously memory usage is lower when I intern.

Comment: The goal of interning strings is not to save memory (although that's a nice side effect), the goal is to *speed up dictionary membership tests*.

Comment: Profile before assuming you are using too much memory. What are you doing that you assume you have multiple copies of identical strings in memory?

Comment: @Martijn: still: same question. :)

Comment: @chepner: I did. It's an issue *sometimes*, and I want to make sure that by solving the issue in the general case by internal, I'm not introducing other issues.

Comment: Another disadvantage of *explicitly* interning strings is sometimes they are *naively* interned by Python anyway, so the `intern()` call is pointless. However, good luck working out when this implementation detail happens; read this: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be two downsides:

- The CPU cost of using the `sys.intern()` call. Calling a function requires the current frame to be pushed on the stack and popped again when the function returns. If you do this for a *lot* of strings the cost adds up. It's a tradeoff of CPU cycles vs. memory you need to take into account.
- You may end up using *more* memory if your strings are mostly used singly. Interning also looks up the string object in a hash table, which by necessity needs to allocate more memory slots than the number of strings stored. Using a hashtable with N + overhead percentage slots *could* outstrip the memory needed for N strings, each used infrequently and thus not duplicated.

That said, we've used interning successfully and to significant effect in a multi-gigabyte in-memory cache, where strings by necessity appear in multiple locations in a tree structure.

Comment: The first one only costs time I think (since the stack frame is released again). Of course pushing on the stack temporary adds a tiny amount of additional memory, but I don't think that is very relevant.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: clarified; I wasn't talking about a memory cost there.

Answer (score 2):

The reduction of memory of course **depends on the number of "duplicates"**. In case there are **no duplicates** this actually only consumes **more memory** since Python also **stores a hashtable** to do lookups for the interning process (it somehow has to check that the string already exists).

Furthermore there are *two* advantages of *string interning*: (1) faster equality checks: you simply compare the references (as you do here with `is`); and (2) *usually* a memory reduction, since you of course aim to intern "interesting" strings.

Comment: This post should really be integrated to the question, but it is the exact opposite of an expected answer...

Comment: How is this the exact opposite of an expected answer. The OP asks if there are downsides memorywise and the answer is: yes, the hashtable itself requires memory as well... Looks like an answer, no?

Comment: Ow, my bad. Then your answer is (no offense) poorly formatted, because the two advantages are literally blinking over the downsides... I genuinely recommend you edit your formatting.

Comment: @Rightleg: swapped the paragraphs. Better?

Comment: Actually, what catches IMO the attention is the list, so I'd swap the *formattings* as well... Meh, it might be only my tastes. Anyway, your post is still good.